# C# Checking elements in xml file

Tags: c#, .net, foreach, element, xelement

I have the below xml file:

```
  <Resources>
    <a>123.png</a>
 </Resources>
 <Resources>
    <a>Background\345.png</a>
 </Resources>
<Resources>
    <b>d1.wav</b>
</Resources>
```

I want to check for the elements to do different function:

```
        foreach (var downloadFile in downloadFiles.Elements("Resources"))
        {
            if (downloadFile.Element("a").Value != null)
            {
                  // function for a
            }
            else if (downloadFile.Element("b").Value != null)
            {
                  // function for b
            }
         }
```

There will be error "`System.NullReferenceException`" when the loop reach element b.

Do you guys know what's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your XML, not all resources have the `b` element, so you get NRE because `Element("b")` returns null. If you want to check whether the element exists compare the `Element` to null without accessing `Value` property:

```
if (downloadFile.Element("b") != null)
```